# opencv macport python bindings

Tags: python, opencv, macports

using the MacPorts install of OpenCV does not seem to install the python bindings anywhere. Are they included, where do they go?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work with any of the answers below?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you selected the +python26 variant for the [MacPorts port](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=opencv)?

```
$ sudo port install opencv +python26
```

Answer (score 7):

I experienced this same issue. It seems the OpenCV Python bindings are built and installed, but they are not referenced in the "site-packages" directory. I have found a solution by adding a symbolic link to the built "cv.so" file in the "site-packages" directory of the Python package installed by MacPorts. These instructions are tested on a setup using Mac OS 10.6.6. The subject MacPorts packages are "python27" and "opencv".

To ensure that the Python bindings are actually on your drive, you will need to ensure you invoked the opencv package with the python variant:

```
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

The "cv.so" shared object file will be built in the following directory:

```
/opt/local/@@PYTHON_PKGD@@
```

It will be necessary to create a symbolic link in your Python's "site-packages" directory. You can find the path to this directory by executing these commands in your Python interpreter:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print get_python_lib()
```

The path returned should be similar to the following:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Create a symbolic link to the shared object ("cv.so") within this directory:

```
ln -s /opt/local/@@PYTHON_PKGD@@/cv.so /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so
```

Now you should be able to import the cv module within your interpreter:

```
import cv
```

Your setup might be slightly different if you are using a different version of Python or OpenCV; however, the general methodology should be the same with the exception of the path names. There may be a better way to do this, but this methodology seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

This should get installed in

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

if you use sudo port install ..

The directories 2.6, 2.5 .. will depend on python version on path.

Thanks Ned, Correcting the above - These are mac os x distribution.

Macports does put every thing under :

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.6/site-packages

Comment: Not likely.  With a couple of exceptions, MacPorts goes to great lengths *not* to install anything anywhere other than under its own root, `/opt/local/` by default.  The MacPorts python2.6 installs site-packages in its `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to have `py26-numpy` installed to have support for basic functions such as `cv.fromarray` :

```
sudo port install py26-numpy
```

`opencv` will compile silently without numpy (it's not *strictly* a dependency).

```
sudo port install -v opencv +python26
```

there you can check that the binding to numpy is effective.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I had to do:

**STEP ONE**

Use Macports to install opencv.

**STEP TWO**

Put these two files somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH` (for example in your `site-packages`):

- https://github.com/jonmrodriguez/opencv-2.3-new-python-bindings/blob/master/cv.py
- https://github.com/jonmrodriguez/opencv-2.3-new-python-bindings/blob/master/cv2.so

**STEP THREE**

Create the below soft links (because `cv2.so` expects the dylibs to be in `/usr/local` but MacPorts installs to `/opt/local`):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.3.dylib libopencv_core.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.3.dylib libopencv_flann.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.3.dylib libopencv_video.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.3.dylib libopencv_ml.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.3.dylib libopencv_features2d.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.3.dylib libopencv_calib3d.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.3.dylib libopencv_objdetect.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.3.dylib libopencv_legacy.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.3.dylib libopencv_contrib.2.3.dylib
```